# Different datatypes in sql

Tags: java, sql, cassandra

I am currently done my storage in cassandra db in which i have list datatype by which we can store n number of values in one column separated by comma.what my doubt is,Is there any datatype in sql to do so.If so,tell me the sql query..

Thanks in advance

Comment: More like your datatype for the one column will be using VARCHAR/String instead as ',' is a character type. The con is that you will not be able to do any arithmetic calculations when you store in a String column. The best way to store values is still using decimal/integer datatype if you need to do calculations, if that's the case, create more columns instead of restricting to 1 column only.

Comment: @Sky...thankz for ur reply...I have to store only varchar values..

Comment: ALTER TABLE _<name>_
   ALTER _<column_name>_ TYPE text

Comment: Use that SQL code to alter your current data table and column to alter to 'text/varchar' datatype.

Comment: @Sky...I am doing this in a java pgm .I have a string which reads from a set of files and i have to store that under one column separated by any delimiter

Comment: Additional info - text datatype is in 'UTF-8 encoded string'. And Java is also using UTF-8 so there shouldn't be much compatiblility issue. Though UTF-8 should have no problem storing ASCII type too.

Comment: how to insert that one by one

Comment: Insert what data one by one? Into Java? Any sample of the codes / data? Your question is unclear. If you can write out a sample of data you want and the current data it will be better.

Comment: for instance I have created table with name as varchar and fields as text.then I am reading a string from a file and insert into fields .Then again I m reading a string now I have to store again into the same field

Comment: Sample data of what the data is currently is, and the desired output. Also, what sql server are you running on?

Comment: eg:input-wayne   output in sql under name field : wayne   then input:Rooney output :wayne,rooney   input:degea output:wayne,Rooney,Degea

Comment: It can be done through SQL. It will be a concat function. The syntax will be depending on what SQL you're using.

Comment: Or another way is to concatenting through Java itself. I'm not sure bout Cassandra.

Comment: i had done concat..but i do have comma in my input so i cant separate it by comma...how to escape comma

Comment: For java you can try using this. String[] names = _name_.split(","); where name = the variable holding the concat String. Your split String will be stored in an array names[]